# Finder Search not working when searching network drive shared with SMB connection on Mojave 10.14.0

Tags: mac, finder, network, mojave, smb

We went through the nightmare of finding out that 10.14.5 Mojave did not allow other Macs to connect via SMB without freezing client's Finders and/or not connecting or dropping connections. To fix that we clean installed 10.14.0 This worked as far as sharing and connecting. The only issue I am having is that when the clients search the Mojave server via Finder or clients Spotlight, no results from the Mojave Server show. This happens on all 14 clients. I have confirmed the Mojave Server has finished indexing. Not sure why none of the clients are able to search the Mojave server. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you re-indexed the network drives for each client?